# Why is JavaScript not setting the value of a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP form to submit and I'm trying to get (vanilla) JavaScript to set the value of a hidden field.  For some reason, the hidden field (deleteRowId) is coming through as blank.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($transcribercertifications)) {
        echo form_open('user/deletecertification/' . $tid, 'id="deleteCert"');
        echo '<table>';
        $count = 0;
        if ($transcribercertifications) {
            foreach ($transcribercertifications as $transcribercertification) {
                echo '<tr><td>' . $transcribercertification . '</td>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="certification[' . $count . ']" id="certification[' . $count . ']" value="' . $transcribercertification . '">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" id="deleteRowId" name="deleteRowId" value="">';
                echo '</td><td title="Delete certification"><button data-row-id="' . $count . '" id="deleteCert" onclick="deleteRow(' . $count . ');">X</button></td></tr>';
                $count++;
            }
        }
        echo '</table>';
        echo form_close();
   }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRow(rowCount) {
        event.preventDefault()
        alert('This will delete the certification. Are you sure ?');
        alert(rowCount); // This value comes through correctly.
        document.getElementById('deleteRowId').value = rowCount;
        document.getElementById('deleteCert').submit();
    }
</script>
```

When the function gets called, deleteRowId is always blank.  If there's another way to set the value of deleteRowId so the function knows which certification to delete, I would be interested in seeing that too.

Comment: can you add `rowCount` to that alert and verify it has a value? Actually, scratch that. Do you even get an alert when you click the button? By all accounts you shouldn't, instead of `onclick="deleteRow(' . $count . ');"` write `onclick="function(){deleteRow(' . $count . ')};"`

Comment: @Dellirium, I did that and the correct value is coming through.

Comment: updated the comment

Comment: `id="deleteRowId"` must be unique

Comment: @Dellirium, thank you.  I will try that.

Comment: You might also want to consider simply writing the value into the field at start in PHP, unless you are changing it with some other client code, as the field is hidden, users won't be able to change it and you can avoid this whole conundrum.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I made the deleteRowId unique and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `id="deleteRowId"` must be unique
and you can use `setAttribute` method

worked exampe

```html
    <input type="hidden" value="111" id="uniqID1">
    <input type="hidden" value="111" id="uniqID2">
    <script>
        let aaa = document.getElementById("uniqID1");
        aaa.setAttribute('value',222);
        console.log(aaa.value)
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Id cannot repeat.**
in foreach loop use as **id="deleteRowId"'.$count.'""**  **id="deleteCert"'.$count.'""**

```
foreach ($transcribercertifications as $transcribercertification) {
                echo '<tr><td>' . $transcribercertification . '</td>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="certification[' . $count . ']" id="certification[' . $count . ']" value="' . $transcribercertification . '">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" id="deleteRowId"'.$count.'"" name="deleteRowId"'.$count.'"" value="">';
                echo '</td><td title="Delete certification"><button data-row-id="' . $count . '" id="deleteCert"'.$count.'"" onclick="deleteRow(' . $count . ');">X</button></td></tr>';
                $count++;
            }
```

and in JS function

```
getElementByID('deleteRowId'+rowCount).
getElementByID('deleteCert'+rowCount)
```